# Redirect with PHP and skip specific parameter

Tags: php, redirect, http-headers

Since I've started using friendly URLS in my website, I'm redirecting every page to the new version, only if the registered user has a "username" in his profile.

**So, I'm redirecting from:**

`https://tribbr.me/post.php?id=850`

**with:**

`header("Location:/".$if_username."/post/".$post_id."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); exit();`

To keep all GET parameters.... but the problem is that this header request, obviously with `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is adding the post id too to the URL, and when redirected, this is the final URL:

`https://tribbr.me/TribeMasters/post/850?id=850`

Is it possible to just skip the `id=850` parameter to the URL redirection? Since it is a duplicated parameter: `post/850` and `id=850` are the same.

Thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Just remove `."?".$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`? There's no reason to pass that in if you don't want it. Or do you have other query parameters you want to pass?

Comment: Yes! Sometimes the post URL is `https://tribbr.me/post.php?id=850&ref=51&fname=Guillermo&more.....`

So I need to redirect to: `https://tribbr.me/username/post/850?ref=51&fnameGuillermo&more...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@DE_`'s answer is best. But If you are not familiar with `Regex`, This is an alternative way.

```
function removeGetParam($param){

 $params = $_GET;

 // removing the key
 unset($params[$param]); 

 // joining and returning the rest
 return implode(',', array_map(function ($value, $key) { 
            return $key.'='.$value;
          },$params, array_keys($params))
        );
}

$filtered_params = removeGetParam('id');
header("Location:/".$if_username."/post/".$post_id."?".$filtered_params);
```

Answer (score 1):

David Walsh did a good article on this

https://davidwalsh.name/php-remove-variable

```
function remove_querystring_var($url, $key) { 
    $url = preg_replace('/(.*)(?|&)' . $key . '=[^&]+?(&)(.*)/i', '$1$2$4', $url . '&'); 
    $url = substr($url, 0, -1); 
    return $url; 
}
```

Comment: thanks for sharing.

What are those `$1$2$4` variables?

Comment: @GuillermoEsquivelObregón those are a group of characters captured in the brackets `()` according to their respective positions

Comment: Thanks for helping me :) For me, worked better with `@BadPiggie` answer since I can't figure out how do I specify `id` parameter in this function, but thanks a lot :)